# How to sum up in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

I want to sum up from a specific cell to above. For example in this photo, H2=G2,G3=H3+H2,G4=H4+H3+H2 and so on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use a dynamic range:

```
=SUM($G$2:$G2)
```

As the last row is not absolute, as the formula is dragged down it will change to the next row and so on.